# Array index automatically starts at 1

Tags: php, html, arrays, laravel, checkbox

I have 2 input types. I have 4 select boxes and 4 checkboxes with hidden fields. The checkboxes have the same name and the select boxes. After submitting, I do this:

```
var_dump(Input::get(checkboxname));
var_dump(Input::get(selectboxname));
```

Which outputs:

```
array(4) { 
  [1]=>   string(5) "value"   
  [2]=>   string(5) "value"  
  [3]=>   string(5) "value" 
  [4]=>   string(5) "value" 
} 
array(4) {  
  [0]=>   string(5) "value"  
  [1]=>   string(5) "value"   
  [2]=>   string(5) "value"
  [3]=>   string(5) "value" 
}
```

This is my select box:

```
<select name="selectboxname[]" >
//values in a complicated for loop that's not important but it works
</select>
```

This is my checkbox:

```
<input  type='hidden' value='othervalue' name='checkboxname[]'>
<input  type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="value">
```

In the arrays, the checkboxes have the index like: 1,2,3,4 and the selectboxes have 0,1,2,3. I have to get the indexes to match with eachother. I know normally the index starts at 0 so the selectboxes are doing it right. What is going wrong here?

Comment: you meant `var_dump($checkboxname);` - otherwise you just output single string

Comment: @n-dru Yup I editted it.

Comment: isn't that because you have a hidden element with the same name as checkbox?

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko I already tried removing the hidden field but it doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you please check the “raw” POST/GET data using `var_dump($_POST)` (resp. $_GET) at the very beginning of your script to rule out any possibility that laravel is doing this?

Comment: @CBroe at this moment, I cant get the error back anymore. Im kinda in the middle of other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-index your array starting from zero, simply do the following:

```
array_values(Input::get('checkboxname'));
```

Comment: Euhm it does. When the checkbox isn't checked, it uses the value of the hidden field.

Comment: When I use `var_dump(array_values(Input::get('checkboxname')));` It will actually give me the right indexes. Still no idea why things are going wrong

Comment: I'm thinking of using `array_values(Input::get('checkboxname'))` then. Since no one can actually figure out the strange behaviour. Explain the `array_values();` in your answer and remove the wrong part about the checkbox not sending any data when I dont check it. I'll accept it after a good edit

Comment: The part about the checkbox wasn't wrong, but since you used an hidden element it wasn't useful to answer the question

Comment: **For future visitors of this question, this doesn't explain the weird behaviour. This is a solution to get the indexes right. Im still looking for the explanation of the behaviour**

Answer (score 0):

```
<input  type='hidden' value='othervalue' name='checkboxname[]'>
<input  type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[]" value="value">
```

seems like the type='hidden' becomes the checkboxname[0].

Comment: If that would be the case, it should still show the value of the hidden field in the array right?

Comment: hmm... you do have a point. try giving a unique value to the hidden then print/echo/alert its value to test it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unchecked value, perhaps you should use numbers in names:

```
<input  type='hidden' value='othervalue' name='checkboxname[0]'>
<input  type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[0]" value="value">
<input  type='hidden' value='othervalue' name='checkboxname[1]'>
<input  type="checkbox" name="checkboxname[1]" value="value">
```

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that I use this in a for loop. I do get the unchecked values. I have a variable between the `[]` So this isn't the case. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Comment: So you can use index value and output it in brackets, this should ensure proper indexes, maybe double check this variable value?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it has to do with how laravel process the input($_POST or $_GET)

Do a var_dump for the one you're using(POST or GET) and see. It might better to access the values directly from $_ arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Try [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to re-index your array

```
<?php
$array = array("size" => "XL", "color" => "gold");
print_r(array_values($array));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => XL
    [1] => gold
)
```